# How to expand or collapse table using js+ jquery in ERB

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby

I'm trying to figure out how to expand and collapse table rows when header(here server-name) is clicked and it should be applied to specific header (i.e. the one that has been clicked).

my app.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="expand.js">  
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> OUTPUT STATISTICS </h1>
<table border="1">
    <% @values.each do |value| %>
     <tr class="server-name">
     <td colspan="3"> <%= value[:server_name]  %> </td>
    </tr>  
    <tr class="members vals">
       <td colspan="2"> NAME </td>
       <td colspan="4"> DATA </td>
       <td colspan="3"> SIZE </td>
    </tr>
    <% value[:attributes].each do |attribute| %>
      <% attribute[:data].each.with_index do |(key, val), i| %>
        <tr class="members">
          <td colspan="2"> <%= i == 0 ? attribute[:name] : ""  %> </td>
          <td colspan="4"> <%= key %></td>
          <td colspan="3"> <%= val %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
      <% if attribute[:data].empty? %>
        <tr class="members">
          <td colspan="2"> <%= attribute[:name] %> </td>
          <td colspan="4"> </td>
          <td colspan="3"> </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
     <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

The output is almost perfect except the expanding and collapsing is not happening when I click on the respective headers or server-name

expand.js

```
$('.server-name').click(function(){
   $(this).find('span').text(function(_, value){return value=='-'?'+':'-'});
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.server-name').slideToggle(500, function(){
    });
});
```

style.css

```
tr.server-name {
    display: table-row;
    font-size:25px;
    font-family:cursive;
    background-color:lightgreen;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
.members {
    font-family:calibri;
}
.vals {
    color:green;
    font-size:17px;
}
```

I'm like a day old to js+ jquery and I'm not sure where I went wrong.

P.S: I'm using only Ruby.

https://jsfiddle.net/p9mtqhm7/521/  [it works in the jsfiddle page but not in my erb template code]

Also I'm calling the .html.erb in my ruby script as

```
opta = File.open(("final.html"), "w+")
opta.puts ERB.new(File.read("app.html.erb")).result binding
```

Comment: Since it works on JSFiddle, I would start by looking at the ERB output. Did you check that the output looks correct?

Comment: @Casper : Firstly thanks for your time, yes , it's working except the expanding and collapsing part, remaining output looks perfect akin to jsfiddle

Comment: Hmm. There has to be a difference. Can you copy the output to JSFiddle and test it there in the same way. Just copypaste the ERB output to JSFiddle to verify if it works there or not.

Comment: Are you sure the browser is loading your .js file. Put an `alert()` call in the .js file or check with the network debugger to verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the document ready handler in your .js file. You have to ensure the DOM is ready before manipulating objects on the page with JavaScript.

It works on JSFiddle because it installs an automatic ready handler for its JavaScript editor box, but in your own code you always have to add the handler yourself.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.server-name').click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.server-name').slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

See the documentation here:
http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Really appreciate your time here, Yes I tried using alert like `<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("Check");
 </script>` and while loading the html page I'm getting the alert "ChecK" or the pop up

Also since I'm new to JS I'm not exactly sure how to append your suggested code to my existing js, should it go like below ?

`$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.server-name').click(function(){
   $(this).find('span').text(function(_, value){return value=='-'?'+':'-'});
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.server-name').slideToggle(500, function(){
    });
});
});`

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot.. I did some minor modifications.. Very nice of you to help a newbie :) and my upvote isn't getting registered..

Comment: @ Casper : Out of curiosity, what should I do do extend my output to occupy the entire page .. CUrrently it's like 1/3rd of the page is getting filled.

Comment: Sound like a CSS formatting question not related to this js problem? If that's the case then it's better to post a new question. Otherwise we will be discussing an unrelated topic here.

Comment: Just google "css fill page vertically". If that's what you're looking for it should give you some ideas. Good luck.

Comment: Yes sir , that's what I've started looking for :) thank you for your suggestion :)